# How to make smooth animation between sliver app bar collapsed and expanded?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

My question is that, I'm learning making smooth animations between sliver app bar collapsed and expanded height. How I can achieve this?

[image]

Above one is collapsed state of sliver app bar(or maybe just made with scroll listening)

[image]

The second is collapsed state. And there is smooth transition between these state. For more detail information you can check my youtube video with animation with the link below
"link: [Sliver App bar transition](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/WJXfyN_0fW4)"